# how to collect results from multiple processor

Tags: parallel-processing

I have done the calculations of a certain variable through multiple processors in cluster, now I want to get all the result from them to a single processor. Which technique I have to use for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking, but GNU Parallel may be what you are looking for:

```
parallel --slf cluster-hosts.txt do_my_procession --my_arg {} ::: {1..1000}
```

Example:

```
parallel -S localhost echo {} ::: {1..1000}
```

See more on: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Remote-execution